# Stochastic calculus integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus

How can I evaluate, or at least find an upper bound for, the following integral without the Hölder inequality, is there an alternate way anyone knows of:

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\sup\left|\int_0^t\mu X(u)du\right|^2\right]?$$

Here $dX = \mu X dt + \sigma X dB$ is the Black Scholes model.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: i tried the holder inequality which simplified, not sure if it was a correct application.  somebody on this forum must have some idea won't they?

Comment: You might want to show what you tried, they explicitely recommend to do so, don't they?

Comment: if someone knew how to solve it they would have solved it, nobody obviously can. I didn't post my solution so i could get someone elses perspective, which i had hoped would have been something different

Comment: Are you asserting that you have a solution? Then it is definitely recommended to include it in the question. (Note that the implication in your first sentence is wrong.)

Comment: Why do you not want to use Holder's inequality?